# Why aren't bounties visible anymore?

Tags: support, feature-request, bounty

In the past, I recall a lot of traffic coming to postings after adding even a 100 point bounty.  And I seem to recall being able to easily find the open bounties and even sort them by number of points offered.

**Has the site stopped promoting bounties?**

I posted a 250 point bounty earlier, but only a couple new people viewed the posting after the bounty was added.  Then I looked around to see how to find open bounties on the site, and all I could find was [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured), which does not make any distinction between 50 point bounties and 500 point bounties.

If the system for publicizing bounties has changed, why make them so much harder to find?

How does a person find open bounties other than the link above?

**I am adding the `bug` tag to this post because the answerer below pointed out that his/her GUI is different than the GUI that I get.  And given that no one has viewed the post in question after the 250 point bounty was posted, it seems clear that bounties are not visible or searchable for the vast majority of stack overflow users.**  It may be that a tiny minority of users like the answerer below see bounties adequately, and that their GUI gives the false impression that anyone else is able to find bounties.

Comment: Yeah... with 399 bounties active right now, we could do a better job at filtering/discovery/etc. However, this is not a bug - the "featured" tab (along with the number of bounties currently offered) is visible on the front page regardless of whether you're using the new experimental UI or not.

Comment: @AnnaLear One cannot even sort bounties by number of points. Each of these sort options would take less than a day to implement and greatly encourage the answerers to spend more time on the site. The absense of such basic filtering is a bug.

Comment: I agree that it sucks, but alas - not a bug in the "not working as designed" sense. Introducing better (or any, really) filtering is very much a feature request. Having said that, the new UI we're working on does introduce ways to sort that list - by bounty size, expiration date, and a few others (along with being able to narrow the list down to specific tags). It is still actively in development, and I don't have an full release ETA for it, but if you're interested in trying it out, you can opt in from your user profile (Edit Profile & Settings > Preferences).

Comment: I'd like to add my voice to CodeMed's.  Setting a bounty to get your question attention and then not getting attention to the question is a big UX issue IMHO.  Because SO has so much noise/activity, it's frustrating if your unbountied question gets overlooked.  Bounties should fix that, but they're not raising your question above the noise.

Comment: @AnnaLear It is a bug because 1.) Users cannot navigate past the first page of results without performing an unnatural act with respect to the image that the GUI presents of there being only one page of results, 2.) The GUI used to provide much better access to bountied posts than it currently provides, and 3.) The current quality level of the bounty GUI is so low that it cannot be considered to be production-ready.  **The current system is a defect.**

Comment: @CodeMed Call it what you want (again, not disputing that there's a problem - and we are working on it), but a developer on "bug duty" isn't going to be redesigning a whole page. So, using "feature request" in our terminology is your best bet here. I'll pass it along internally to see if we can speed this up.

Answer (score 4):

(Using the new nav,) I see a searingly blue xyz bounties button on the right side, leftmost of the buttons there, independent of which view I use.
If there's at least one question with a bounty fitting my current criteria, at least.

Imho, that's quite promotional enough.

Also, it allows sorting lots of different ways.

Comment: Can you post a link to the page where you see that?  All I get is the featured tab in the link in my OP, which shows bounties but no way of sorting by number of points offered.  This seems ratified by only 2 additional views in the first 2 hours of offering a 250 point bounty.  It is as if the bounty made no difference, and the two new viewers would have clicked on the posting anyway.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/need-answers?show=bounties&sort=ending But I guess you aren't on the new nav? In that case, I don't know where that link will send you...

Comment: The link you gave gives me a page not found error.

Comment: Well, that proves it. And an interesting choice for the interim...

Answer (score 3):

I am able to see your bounty with both the old navigation and the new navigation.

Using the **old (default) navigation**, your bounty currently appears on page 8 (if you are allowing 50 questions per page):

[image: Bounty - Old Nav]

You can get to this by selecting, from the main page, the Featured Tab. At the very bottom of the page, select "Browse complete list", as only a handful are shown initially.

[image: Complete list]

If you are showing 50 questions per page, navigate to page 8. Find your bounty and be happy.

---

On the **new navigation**, click on the button showing how many active bounties there are:

[image: Active bounties]

Sort by ending date (to replicate how the old navigation works) and go to page 8.

[image: Bounties - New Nav]

Again, your bounty is listed on this page if you have 50 questions per page:

[image: Listed bounty - new nav]

Comment: Page 8 is not acceptable for a 250 point bounty that was just posted. Both the recency of posting and the number of points should separately rise it to the top.

Comment: It sorts by soonest to end, on the default method of navigation. That hasn't changed. The newest bounties are at the end of the list. I agree that would difficult to stomach if sorting by bounty size (on the new navigation)

Comment: Which brings up this related [bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263828/what-is-the-bounty-size-sort-actually-sorting-by-in-new-nav) I created while researching this answer.

Comment: What you are describing is completely unacceptable. I recall a much more effective search in the past, though it has been a long time since I looked into it.  We just assume such things have been well engineered, and it is disappointing to see poor engineering.